# Getting image to fit within view

Tags: css, image, react-native

Im trying to get an image to fit within my view but it overshoots the view and covers most of the screen. I have tried other solutions I've found like resizeMode: "contain"/cover but none seem to fix it.

Heres my code:

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.articlePicture}>
        <Image source={require("../../assets/powerplant.jpg")} style={styles.image}></Image>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
        <View style={styles.articleSubTitle}>
          <Text>Travel</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.articleTitle}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

And here is my styles:

```
  container: {
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "blue",
  },
  contentContainer: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "10%",
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
  },
  articlePicture: {
    height: "20%",
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
  articleTitle: {},
  title: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  articleSubTitle: {},
  image: {
    height: "100%",
    flexDirection: "column",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    aspectRatio: 1,
    resizeMode: "contain",
  },
```

Comment: try to add the resizeMode as props not as style and give width 100% too its also required
<Image source={require("../../assets/powerplant.jpg")} style={styles.image} resizeMode="contain"></Image>

Comment: @KathirpandianK passing it as props seemed to slightly contain the image slightly rather than covering the screen and giving width of 100% made no difference

Answer (score 0):

**Use CSS `object-fit: cover;`**

I think something like bellow:

```
...
 image: {
    height: "100%",
    flexDirection: "column",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    aspectRatio: 1,
    objectFit: "cover",
  },
....
```